# Get height need to fit string in UILabel

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.iOS app, I have a UILabel who's width is 300 and contains a very long string. I need to resize the frame of the `UILabel` so that its height is what is needed to fit the entire string while keeping the width at 300.

```
UILabel myLabel;
myLabel.Text = "VERY LONG STRING!!!!!!!!111.....youGetThePoint"
myLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20, UIFontWeight.Bold);
// now I want to make myLabel's width 300 and the height to be the appropriate amount to see the whole text.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`UILabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize size)`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIView.SizeThatFits/p/CoreGraphics.CGSize/):

```
UILabel myLabel = ...;
myLabel.Text = "VERY LONG STRING!!!!!!!!111.....youGetThePoint"
myLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20, UIFontWeight.Bold);
myLabel.PreferredMaxLayoutWidth = 300
myLabel.Lines = 0

var maxSize = new CGSize((nfloat)300, nfloat.MaxValue);
var labelSize = myLabel.SizeThatFits(maxSize);
```

`labelSize` should give you the size of that very long text that the label displays.

```
myLabel.Frame.Height = labelSize.Height;
```